# How to pass an argument to 2nd command when using `concurrently` with npm?

Tags: npm, jestjs, ts-jest, concurrently

I have 2 npm scripts: `tsc -w` and `jest --watch` that I want to execute concurrently. I know there is a tool called `concurrently` that could be used for this.

```json
"test:watch": "concurrently -P --kill-others \"npm run watch\"  \"jest --watchAll -- {@} \"",
```

Problem is I want to pass a param to the Jest command, and not to the `concurrently` command.

How to pass an argument to the 2nd command when using `concurrently` with `npm`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the pass-through flag to pass arguments from your command line to the script.

```json
"test:watch": "concurrently -P --kill-others \"npm run watch\"  \"jest --watchAll -- {@} \"",
```

Use it like this:

```bash
npm run test:watch -- -- cookie
```

You need to use `--` twice to reach the inner Jest script!